# Date Table Sort PHP Page--- MySql

Tags: php, html, mysql

**Hi Everyone,
I would like to sort my table by date but I couldn't sort it.
Hope you guys can help me.**

**Here's my code**

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered bootstrap-datatable datatable responsive">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Action</th>
<th>Date and Time</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php
$result= mysql_query("select * from history order by history_id DESC ") or die (mysql_error());
while ($row= mysql_fetch_array ($result) ){
$id=$row['history_id'];
?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $row['data']; ?></td>
<td><span class="label-primary label label-default"><?php echo $row['action']; ?></span></td>
<td><span class="label-success label label-default"><?php echo date("M d, Y H:i:s",strtotime($row['date'])); ?></span></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Welcome To Stack Overflow. *Claps*

Comment: `select * from history order by history_id DESC,date DESC` do you know? mysql_* is closed in php 7

Comment: do u want Latest to Oldest according to date or history id??

Comment: the latest or the current

Comment: It usually sorted by names tho. I want dates.

Comment: select * from history order by date DESC

Comment: I couldn't sorted still.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to paste the code, and so I hope this is what you wanted:

Sort table by date, descendingly:

```
ALTER TABLE table1
ORDER BY table1.Date DESC,
```

Sort table by date, ascendingly:

```
ALTER TABLE table1
ORDER BY table1.Date ASC
```

Comment: Why would you alter table?

Comment: This is for my Php page tho, is there anyway I can sorted it by date?

Comment: @barudo In order to sort the table.@Obscurious Queen Yes, you just have to run that SQL on your PHP query

Comment: @ObscuriousQueen Update your SQL: SELECT * FROM HISTORY ORDER BY date DESC

Comment: I already did but it's the same thing, I'm thinking if it's the JQuery on my bootstrap,

Comment: Are you using MySQL?